# SkLearn calls nested cross validation something which is not

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I was reading the docs of SkLearn around nested cross validation and I discovered at this  [SkLearn page](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_nested_cross_validation_iris.html) the following example of nested cross validation:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score, KFold
import numpy as np

print(__doc__)

# Number of random trials
NUM_TRIALS = 30

# Load the dataset
iris = load_iris()
X_iris = iris.data
y_iris = iris.target

# Set up possible values of parameters to optimize over
p_grid = {"C": [1, 10, 100],
          "gamma": [.01, .1]}

# We will use a Support Vector Classifier with "rbf" kernel
svm = SVC(kernel="rbf")

# Arrays to store scores
non_nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)
nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)

# Loop for each trial
for i in range(NUM_TRIALS):

    # Choose cross-validation techniques for the inner and outer loops,
    # independently of the dataset.
    # E.g "LabelKFold", "LeaveOneOut", "LeaveOneLabelOut", etc.
    inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
    outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)

    # Non_nested parameter search and scoring
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
    clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
    non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_

    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
    nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()

score_difference = non_nested_scores - nested_scores

print("Average difference of {0:6f} with std. dev. of {1:6f}."
      .format(score_difference.mean(), score_difference.std()))

# Plot scores on each trial for nested and non-nested CV
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
non_nested_scores_line, = plt.plot(non_nested_scores, color='r')
nested_line, = plt.plot(nested_scores, color='b')
plt.ylabel("score", fontsize="14")
plt.legend([non_nested_scores_line, nested_line],
           ["Non-Nested CV", "Nested CV"],
           bbox_to_anchor=(0, .4, .5, 0))
plt.title("Non-Nested and Nested Cross Validation on Iris Dataset",
          x=.5, y=1.1, fontsize="15")

# Plot bar chart of the difference.
plt.subplot(212)
difference_plot = plt.bar(range(NUM_TRIALS), score_difference)
plt.xlabel("Individual Trial #")
plt.legend([difference_plot],
           ["Non-Nested CV - Nested CV Score"],
           bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1, .8, 0))
plt.ylabel("score difference", fontsize="14")

plt.show()
```

I do not know if I am missing something but is this exactly an example of nested cross validation?

In my view, the **problem** is that at this example there both the parameter optimisation and the model evaluation are done with the same dataset while properly the former should be done with the training & validation sets and the latter with the test set.

Specifically, at this example, both the "inner" and "outer" loops are using the whole of `X_iris` and `y_iris` since:

- `clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)` (Grid Search)
- `cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)`

Comment: Your question is unclear; the existence of any test set is independent of & external to the CV procedure which, generally speaking, involves the creation of *training* and *validation* folds (but not *test* ones) from the initial data...

Comment: Yes, exactly but at the SkLearn example it is written `clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)` and `cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)` that is that both the hyperparameter optimization and the model evaluation are done exactly with the same `X_iris` and `y_iris`.

Comment: Any ideas @desertnaut? Where have you gone suddenly?

Comment: Sorry no, busy with stuff... But I concur that the terminology used by sklearn here ("nested", "inner", "outer") is indeed puzzling & not justifiable by their code example (so, +1 for your question)...

Comment: No worries...Sometimes I am wondering how other data scientists  did not spot things like these before for so long time...haha...

Comment: Sometimes newcomers can spot such things much easier (have never looked at this myself); but BTW, in other cases they can get unnecessarily confused by over-reading things (re your other Q on `LabelEncoder`)...

Comment: Haha, ok. However, believe me that I did not over-read anything regarding LabelEncoder(). I just listened to a senior Data Scientist saying something which at best was not clear enough. Anyways, thanks for the comments so far!

Comment: See my answer on the description of above here:https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230764/3374996

Comment: Thanks @VivekKumar. However, I do not understand how your answer there responds to my question. Are you simply saying there that what is called nested cross validation in the SkLearn's docs is essentially a twice repeated cross validation? If so then this was exactly my point.

Comment: Check this out. I tried to explain there about nested CV - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138897/fitting-in-nested-cross-validation-with-cross-val-score-with-pipeline-and-gridse/52147410#52147410

Comment: Nice one @ShaharA (upvote) but I had in mind what is nested cross validation when I was writing my post. My point was that what SkLearn calls nested cross validation is not a real one.

Comment: @Poete - you're totally right. they do not use the current fold of the outer CV in the inner CV in their example, but the entire dataset, which is wrong and misleading

Comment: @ShaharA ;) ...

Comment: @ShaharA, @PoeteMaudit, I know I'm late to the party, but sklearn's nested example is actually fine. The most confusing bit is their use of `clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)` before sending it into `cross_val_score`. However, `cross_val_score` will **refit** `clf` (see how in their example they provide an unfitted classifier: [`cross_val_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score)) - this time, when fitting inside `cross_val_score`, it will be fitted using the correct folds. I hope that clears it.