# Cross-validation and parameters tuning with XGBoost and hyperopt

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, xgboost

One way to do nested cross-validation with a XGB model would be:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score
from xgboost import XGBClassifier

# Let's assume that we have some data for a binary classification
# problem : X (n_samples, n_features) and y (n_samples,)...

gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=XGBClassifier(), 
                  param_grid={'max_depth': [3, 6, 9], 
                              'learning_rate': [0.001, 0.01, 0.05]}, 
                  cv=2)
scores = cross_val_score(gs, X, y, cv=2)
```

However, regarding the tuning of XGB parameters, several tutorials (such as [this one](https://www.dataiku.com/learn/guide/code/python/advanced-xgboost-tuning.html)) take advantage of the Python [hyperopt](http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/) library. I would like to be able to do nested cross-validation (as above) using hyperopt to tune the XGB parameters.

To do so, I wrote my own Scikit-Learn estimator:

```
from hyperopt import fmin, tpe, hp, Trials, STATUS_OK
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.exceptions import NotFittedError
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from xgboost import XGBClassifier


def optimize_params(X, y, params_space, validation_split=0.2):
     """Estimate a set of 'best' model parameters."""
     # Split X, y into train/validation
     X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=validation_split, stratify=y)

    # Estimate XGB params
    def objective(_params):
        _clf = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=10000,
                             max_depth=int(_params['max_depth']),
                             learning_rate=_params['learning_rate'],
                             min_child_weight=_params['min_child_weight'],
                             subsample=_params['subsample'],
                             colsample_bytree=_params['colsample_bytree'],
                             gamma=_params['gamma'])
        _clf.fit(X_train, y_train,
                 eval_set=[(X_train, y_train), (X_val, y_val)],
                 eval_metric='auc',
                 early_stopping_rounds=30)
        y_pred_proba = _clf.predict_proba(X_val)[:, 1]
        roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_true=y_val, y_score=y_pred_proba)
        return {'loss': 1. - roc_auc, 'status': STATUS_OK}

    trials = Trials()
    return fmin(fn=objective,
                space=params_space,
                algo=tpe.suggest,
                max_evals=100,
                trials=trials,
                verbose=0)


class OptimizedXGB(BaseEstimator, ClassifierMixin):
    """XGB with optimized parameters.

    Parameters
    ----------
    custom_params_space : dict or None
        If not None, dictionary whose keys are the XGB parameters to be
        optimized and corresponding values are 'a priori' probability
        distributions for the given parameter value. If None, a default
        parameters space is used.
    """
    def __init__(self, custom_params_space=None):
        self.custom_params_space = custom_params_space

    def fit(self, X, y, validation_split=0.3):
        """Train a XGB model.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_features)
            Data.

        y : ndarray, shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_labels)
            Labels.

        validation_split : float (default: 0.3)
            Float between 0 and 1. Corresponds to the percentage of samples in X which will be used as validation data to estimate the 'best' model parameters.
        """
        # If no custom parameters space is given, use a default one.
        if self.custom_params_space is None:
            _space = {
                'learning_rate': hp.uniform('learning_rate', 0.0001, 0.05),
                'max_depth': hp.quniform('max_depth', 8, 15, 1),
                'min_child_weight': hp.quniform('min_child_weight', 1, 5, 1),
                'subsample': hp.quniform('subsample', 0.7, 1, 0.05),
                'gamma': hp.quniform('gamma', 0.9, 1, 0.05),
                'colsample_bytree': hp.quniform('colsample_bytree', 0.5, 0.7, 0.05)
            }
        else:
            _space = self.custom_params_space

        # Estimate best params using X, y
        opt = optimize_params(X, y, _space, validation_split)

        # Instantiate `xgboost.XGBClassifier` with optimized parameters
        best = XGBClassifier(n_estimators=10000,
                             max_depth=int(opt['max_depth']),
                             learning_rate=opt['learning_rate'],
                             min_child_weight=opt['min_child_weight'],
                             subsample=opt['subsample'],
                             gamma=opt['gamma'],
                             colsample_bytree=opt['colsample_bytree'])
        best.fit(X, y)
        self.best_estimator_ = best
        return self

    def predict(self, X):
        """Predict labels with trained XGB model.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_features)

        Returns
        -------
        output : ndarray, shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_labels)
        """
        if not hasattr(self, 'best_estimator_'):
            raise NotFittedError('Call `fit` before `predict`.')
        else:
            return self.best_estimator_.predict(X)

    def predict_proba(self, X):
        """Predict labels probaiblities with trained XGB model.

        Parameters
        ----------
        X : ndarray, shape (n_samples, n_features)

        Returns
        -------
        output : ndarray, shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_labels)
        """
        if not hasattr(self, 'best_estimator_'):
            raise NotFittedError('Call `fit` before `predict_proba`.')
        else:
            return self.best_estimator_.predict_proba(X)
```

My questions are:

- Is this a valid approach? For instance, in the `fit` method of my `OptimizedXGB`, `best.fit(X, y)` will train a XGB model on X, y. However, this might lead to overfitting as no `eval_set` is specified to ensure early stopping.
- On a toy example (the famous iris dataset), this `OptimizedXGB` performs worse than a basic LogisticRegression classifier. Why is that? Is it because the example is to simplistic? See below for the code of the example.

**Example**:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score, StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)
X = X[:, :2]
X = X[y < 2]
y = y[y < 2]
skf = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=2, random_state=42)

# With a LogisticRegression classifier
pipe = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()), ('lr', LogisticRegression())])
gs = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe, param_grid={'lr__C': [1., 10.]})
lr_scores = cross_val_score(gs, X, y, cv=skf)

# With OptimizedXGB
xgb_scores = cross_val_score(OptimizedXGB(), X, y, cv=skf)

# Print results
print('Accuracy with LogisticRegression = %.4f (+/- %.4f)' % (np.mean(lr_scores), np.std(lr_scores)))
print('Accuracy with OptimizedXGB = %.4f (+/- %.4f)' % (np.mean(xgb_scores), np.std(xgb_scores)))
```

Outputs:

```
Accuracy with LogisticRegression = 0.9900 (+/- 0.0100)
Accuracy with OptimizedXGB = 0.9100 (+/- 0.0300)
```

Although the scores are close, I would have expected the XGB model to score at least as well as a LogisticRegression classifier.

**EDIT:**

- [similar post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/183984/how-to-use-xgboost-cv-with-hyperparameters-optimization)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, check this post - might help - [nested CV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138897/fitting-in-nested-cross-validation-with-cross-val-score-with-pipeline-and-gridse/52147410#52147410).

Regarding your questions:

1. Yes, that's the right way to go. Once you have your hyper parameters selected, you should fit your model (selected model) on the entire training data. However, since this model includes a model selection process inside, you can only "score" how well it generalizes using an external CV, like you did.
2. Since you are scoring the selection process as well (and not just the model, say XGB Vs Linear regression) there might be some problem with the selection process. Maybe you hyper space is not properly defined and you are choosing poor parameters?